# how to get the child names when i select the parent in the tree view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI tree view with check boxes implementation.
I am able to check all children's check boxes,when i select the parent checkbox.
now,I want to get all the children's text values when i select the parent check box.
I used template for check box operation in tree view

```
$("#ProjectUsersTreeView [type=checkbox]").live('change', function (e) {                       var chkbox = $(this);
                        var parent = chkbox.parent();                            
    var pBox = $(parent).closest('.k-item').find(":checkbox");                               

                       if (this.checked || pBox.length>0) {
                           $(pBox).prop('checked',this.checked ? "checked": "")      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using your code for checking children I do recommend using KendoUI configuration option checkChildren.

```
tree = $("#ProjectUsersTreeView").kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes:{
                checkChildren: true
            },
            ...
        }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Then for getting all selected text use:

```
$("#ProjectUsersTreeView [type=checkbox]").live('change', function (e) {
            var checked = $("input:checked", tree);
            $.each(checked, function(idx, elem) {
                console.log("text", tree.text(elem));
            })
        });
```

In `checked` I get all `input` elements from the tree that are actually `checked` and display its text on console by getting it using `text` method.

*NOTE*: Realize that I've defined `tree` as `$("#ProjectUsersTreeView").data("kendoTreeView")` and then use it in `change` handler.